# How to run a python script multiple times?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have an automation script and I want to run it 1000 times , how can I do it?

i want to automate some online tasks and i'm a beginner so i haven't tried anything yet

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').click()
```

it's just a usual selenium script

Answer (score 0):

You could include it in a for loop and do it 1000 times like this

```py
    for x in range(1000):
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').click()
```

Comment: `range` is half-open, so your loop only iterates 999 times.

Comment: I edited the answer to do it 1000 times, thanks for the notice but the idea was still there